# Export from Java EE + Struts2 to DOC files

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, jasper-reports, docx, doc

Someone knows any java library that allows me to export information to doc format, I appreciate variety.

My project is using Java EE and STRUTS2. So I need to evaluate and to compare the options.

For example JASPERREPORTS.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/

Comment: Hi @UmeshAwasthi, I reviewed the page but it doesn't respond my question

Comment: I believe POI is best way to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good option is [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/). I have used it with Excel documents but it also provides support for handling .doc files.

[Here](http://tkgospodinov.com/writing-microsoft-word-documents-in-java-with-apache-poi/) is an example.

Comment: Thanks, but, based on your opinion, with POI i really get good results. Cause I have to manage a lot of information for show it, on this sense, it should be interesting for users

Comment: People have weighed in on POI, it is good and easy. There is also OpenOffice UNO, there are a lot of great features there unfortunately it isn't really designed to work with Java as a first class citizen and is a nightmare to use. Consider only if POI isn't able to do what you need. Disappointed that when there was backlash at Sun using too much Java in OpenOffice... having a decent document editing capabilities in the form of Java APIs today would mean a lot, who does most of their business programming is C++? Bit short sited not to stick to their guns.